# Given an urn with $40$ balls: $10$ white,$10$ black,$10$ red, $10$ green.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

We extract $2$ balls (simultaneously). What is the probability that at least one of them to be a white ball?

Comment: What have you tried?  You might as well pick one first, then another.  What is the chance that the first ball is white?  Given that it is not, what is the chance the second one is?

Comment: I thought this problem would be solved with hipergeometrical scheme but in this problem it said that it should be at least a white ball and that confuses me

Comment: Follow through on the suggestion from @Ross, Mary. Let's take it one step at a time. If you just pick one ball, what is the probability that it is white?

Comment: @GerryMyerson $1/40$ ?

Comment: Good! Now, suppose the first ball isn't white. What is the probability that the second ball is white?

Comment: well, i think $1/39$ ?

Comment: But this problem cannot be solved with probabilistical schema?(bernoulli/poisson..)

Comment: Sorry, first answer should have been $10/40$, not $1/40$. Then second ball is $10/39$. So the probability of at least one white is $(10/40)+(30/40)(10/39)$ This is $(1/4)+(5/26)=23/52$.

Comment: Anyway, it's better to understand probability well enough to work your way through to the answer, than it is to grab for some "schema" that you don't understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the event $X$= 
you dont pick a white ball.

Numbers of combinations to pick two balls : $40 \choose 2 $

Number of combinations to pick two balls that are not white : $30 \choose 2 $

Therefore the probability to pick two non-white balls is $$P(X)=\frac{30 \choose 2 }{40 \choose 2 }$$

We know that $X^c$= You pick at least one white ball, thus
$$P(X^c)=1-\frac{30 \choose 2 }{40 \choose 2 }$$

Answer (score 3):

### Solve by counting:

- **Direct**: "At least one white" = ("Two white") or ("One white and one non-white"): $$
  \frac{\binom{10}{2}}{\binom{40}{2}}+\frac{\binom{10}{1}\binom{30}{1}}{\binom{40}{2}}=\frac{23}{52}
  $$ Where $P(X)=P(X_1\text{ or }X_2)=P(X_1)+P(X_2)$ since $X_1,X_2$ are disjoint events.
- **Complement:** "Pick $x\ge 1$ white" is opposite of "Pick $x\lt 1$ white (that is, pick $0$ whites)": $$
  1-\frac{30 \choose 2 }{40 \choose 2 }=\frac{23}{52}
  $$ Where $P(X)=P(\text{not }X_0)=1-P(X_0)$ due to $X_0$ being a complement of $X$.

### Solve by probability tree:

1. Chances of first ball being white is $\frac{10}{40}$, and of not being white is $\frac{30}{40}$.
2. If first is white, we are done (don't care about the second pick as we already have at least one white in this scenario). If first is not white (And don't forget we have $\frac{30}{40}$ chance of finding ourselves in this scenario), we now have $\frac{10}{39}$ of second ball being white (first pick took out one non-white ball). Summing up both scenarios: $$
   \frac{10}{40}+\frac{30}{40}\cdot\frac{10}{39}=\frac{23}{52} $$